# How to change my SAS code to find the maximum number

Tags: sas

I have a dataset looks like this. I want to create another variable which represent the total trading volume each day. My code shown below. But it seems that there is something wrong with my code, the calculated maximum trading volume `N` is wrong somehow. Can anyone tell me know where is my mistake please.

```
proc sort data = work.data;
by time;
run;

data work.data;
    set work.data;
    retain I; 
    by time;
    if first.time then I = volume; else I = I + volume;
run;

proc sql;
    create table work.data2
    as select a.*,  max(I) as N 
    from work.data as a  
    group by time
    order by time;
quit; 

ID      Time        Volume
Apple   1/1/2001    1000
BP      1/1/2001    1500
AAL     2/1/2001    1130
Apple   2/1/2001    1000
BP      2/1/2001    1500
AAL     2/1/2001    1130
Apple   3/1/2001    1000
BP      3/1/2001    1500
AAL     3/1/2001    1130
```

Comment: When I run your code on your example dataset I get the correct maximum by day. Can you add your unexpected result to the post?

Comment: In this case, I guess there might be something wrong with the format of volume.  In my SAS dataset, the format of volume is $52.  The length should not be this long.  Will this cause some problem?

Comment: Is `volume` character or numeric? In your first data step, try doing `volume2 = input(cats(volume), best.);` then doing operations on `volume2` in place of `volume`.

Comment: If the variable is character, it takes the max according to alphabetical order, so 9 is greater than 10.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Volume is a numeric variable. I changed it as you said, the result improves but still wrong. I guess this time the problem is something wrong with the format of `time`.  variable `time` looks like 01-JAN-2000. The length of `time` is 8, format is Date11., informat is Date11.  Do you think whether I need to reformat the date or not?

Comment: Why would you have a character format applied to a numeric variable?  As Alex has requested - post sample input/output.

Comment: @fly36 The date format shouldn't affect it at all since you're merely grouping by time, not performing any operations on time.

Comment: The problem is caused by the format of `volume`. I reformatted it, and it works now.  Thank you so much for helping me find my stupid mistake.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should max(I) as your condition. Something like: having I=max(I); Also try this by one proc sql.

```
proc sql;
select * from (select time,sum(volume) as total from have group by time)   having total=max(total);
quit;
```

Comment: This isn't what the OP is asking for. You're getting the time with the largest sum of volume, whereas the OP wants the maximum volume per time.